# Segfault on list.clear()

Tags: c++, list, boost, stl, segmentation-fault

I have an object that inherits a list (currently `boost::ptr_list<Command>`, although `std::list<Command *>` threw the exact same error) like so:

```
class Command : public Serializable
{
protected:
    bool queued;
    Selector unit;
    long double time;

public:
    Command(Selector unit, bool queued, long double time) :unit(unit)
    {
        this->queued = queued;
        this->time = time;
    };

    bool getQueued(){ return queued; };
    Selector getUnit(){ return unit; };

    virtual void issue(World * world) = 0;
};

class CommandList : public Serializable, public boost::ptr_list<Command>
{
public:
    CommandList(){};
    CommandList(ptree serial) { deserialize(serial); };

    virtual void issue(World * world);

    ptree serialize();
    void deserialize(ptree serial);

    static CommandList * deserializedCommandList(ptree serial){ return new CommandList(serial); }
    static Serializable * returnDeserialized(ptree serial){return deserializedCommandList(serial);}
};
```

I create an instance of said object, like so:

```
class Client
{
public:
    CommandList commandList;
....
}
```

and later, try to call two of its functions within another function:

```
void Client::Networking::clientNetworkThing(Client * client)
{
    ...
        string out = ptreeToString(client->commandList.serialize());
        cout << "out: " << out;
    ...
        client->commandList.clear();
    ...
}
```

The first succeeds, but the program crashes on the line where clear() is called, with visual studio reporting the error:

```
"Unhandled exception at 0x638A3703 (msvcr120d.dll) in moba_source.exe: 0xC0000005:
Access violation writing location 0x008EB7F0."
```

And in the watch pane, it says (referring to commandList):

```
a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object
```

Comment: I bet the problem is in the `...` or unpublished code... What does the destructor for `Command` look like? Do you ever copy `Client` objects? Can you make a small but complete program that we can inspect, that shows the problem?

Comment: It's seen as bad by many people to [inherit from the standard containers](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/stl/article.php/c4143/Working-with-the-Final-Class-in-C.htm), mainly because of the lack of a virtual destructor.

Comment: I'm going to take a wild guess and say this is probably the result of a rule of 3 violation ...

Comment: @MatsPetersson I didn't declare a custom destructor for `Command` (I've now posted the full declaration) since it contains no pointers, nor do I ever copy the Client object (it only exists once). I'll try to make a smaller one that duplicates the problem...

Comment: Ultimately, it turned out to be a problem involving initializing a char * between when I called `commandList.serialize()` and `commandList.clear()`. Why this effected the `commandList` object, I'll never know...